# Convert string to cell reference that can be passed to function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a cell reference to pass to a function.
I have a cell that looks like this:

```
=INDIRECT(sheetName() + "!B5:F5")
```

where sheetName is a custom function. I get this error:
Error
Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But 'October' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
Where "sheetName()" returns "October". What on earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the '&' instead of '+'. That has worked for me when using indirect.